# Making the Looped Data from GetJson Array a Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem, im making a list for the markers on my Google Maps but i want it to make a link that will display the Values of that on the List, it is looped by getJson and the `<li>` is only appended upon loop.

Can someone help me making it a Link that will alert the values?

This is my sets of codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    //var mgr;

    function initialize() {
        var minZoomLevel = 4;
        var zooms = 7;
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: minZoomLevel,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.50, -90.50),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        // Bounds for North America
        var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
     new google.maps.LatLng(15.70, -160.50),
     new google.maps.LatLng(68.85, -55.90)
   );

        // Listen for the dragend event
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function () {
            if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;

            // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds

            var c = map.getCenter(),
         x = c.lng(),
         y = c.lat(),
         maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
         maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
         minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
         minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

            if (x < minX) x = minX;
            if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
            if (y < minY) y = minY;
            if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
        });


        // Limit the zoom level
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
            if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);
        });

        codeAddress();

    }
    var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
    function codeAddress() {
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        $.getJSON('/Dashboard/LoadWorkerList', function (address) {
            $.each(address, function () {
                var currVal = this["AddressLine1"];
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': currVal }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            icon: iconBase + 'man.png',
                            position: results[0].geometry.location,
                            title: currVal

                        })

                        $('#places').append($('<li/>')
                                    .text(currVal)
                                    .data('location', results[0].geometry.location));

                        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {
                            $('#places li').css('display', function () {
                                return (map.getBounds().contains($(this).data('location')))
                      ? ''
                      : 'none';
                            });
                        });

                        //mgr = new MarkerManager(map);


                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                            return function () {
                                infowindow.setContent(currVal);
                                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                            }
                        })(marker, currVal));
                        address.push(marker);

                    }
                    else if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
                        setTimeout(codeAddress, 2000);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                    }
                });
            });
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'bounds_changed');
        });
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        initialize();

    }

</script>
```

LoadWorkerList:

```
public JsonResult LoadWorkerList()
        {
            var workerList = new List<Worker_Address>();

            // check if search string has value
            // retrieve list of workers filtered by search criteria
            var list = (from a in db.Worker_Address
                        where a.LogicalDelete == false
                        select a).ToList();



            List<WorkerAddressInfo> wlist = new List<WorkerAddressInfo>();
            foreach (var row in list)
            {
                WorkerAddressInfo ci = new WorkerAddressInfo
                {
                    ID = row.ID,
                    Worker_ID = row.WorkerID,
                    AddressLine1 = row.Address_Line1 + " " + row.Address_Line2+ " " +row.City + " "+ GetLookupDisplayValById(row.State_LookID),
                    LogicalDelete = row.LogicalDelete

                };
                wlist.Add(ci);
            }


            return Json(wlist.ToList().OrderBy(p => p.AddressLine1), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: What is content of `/Dashboard/LoadWorkerList`?

Comment: You have `append($('<li/>')`. It should be without `/`: `append($('<li>')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line:

```
$('#places').append($('<li/>')
```

should be changed. **/** in front of **>** should be removed:

```
$('#places').append($('<li>')
```

If the list with ID *places* is available you will get the list of addresses.